# How to comment Ansible variables

Tags: ansible

I want to setup 2 Kafka cluster on the same host. I have defined variables under `host_vars/HOSTNAME` file which looks like as following:

```yaml
Kafka_cluster_path: /home/cluster1
# Kafka_cluster_path: /home/cluster2
```

I have a template which uses `cluster_id` as following:

```yaml
{{ Kafka_cluster_path }}/kafka/start.sh
```

When I run my Ansible role, it fills template with **`Kafka_cluster_path =/home/cluster2`**.

**Is there a way to really comment a variable in Ansible?**

BTW, when I remove commented line:

```yaml
Kafka_cluster_path: /home/cluster1
```

and run the Ansible role then `kafka_cluster_path` gets the correct value (`/home/cluster1`).

Comment: Save your file before running again or look where this variable is defined again (inventory, other included file). From the above, your variable is commented out.

Comment: I tried it and I am positive that you can not comment variables from hosts file in Ansible 2.6.17

Comment: Ansible files are written in yaml. See the spec: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2780069

Comment: @Zeitounator did you try out ? I posted question because expected outcome does not match with the actual outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is the actual way of commenting out a variable in a yaml file and I do not see any problem with what you have described in your question.

From the comments above, since your are not totally convinced by the [official yaml specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2780069), here is a full MCVE created from your description to prove it absolutely works as expected:

in `host_vars/localhost`

```yaml
---
Kafka_cluster_path: /home/cluster1
# Kafka_cluster_path: /home/cluster2
```

in `play.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: "Prove that ansible obeys yaml spec and honors comments as expected"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
 
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Kafka_cluster_path }}/kafka/start.sh"
```

Please note below that I installed in a virtualenv the same ansible version you are using (which by the way is quite old and you should consider upgrading) to rule out any left over doubt.

```sh
(test) $ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.6.17
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /tmp/test/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /tmp/test/test/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) [GCC 8.3.0]

(test) $ ansible-playbook play.yml 

PLAY [Prove that ansible obeys yaml spec and honors comments as expected] **************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/home/cluster1/kafka/start.sh"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I will try again and see why it did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Ansible uses roles and playbooks to organize and reuse code. Roles encapsulate specific functionalities, while playbooks string together roles to achieve higher-level objectives.